# Declare Floating Environment options

Tags: floats, floating

i'm creating new Floating Environment like figures,

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage{newfloat}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[ fileext=lop,
listname={List de figure Partie 2}, name=FIGURE,placement=tp, ]{plot}

\begin{document}

\begin{plot}
  hhh
\caption{zzz}
\end{plot}
\end{document}
```

the problem is that the result is: FIGURE 5.1 and i want it to be : FIGURE 5 
i tried with the `\renewcommand{}{\arabic{}}`
but i dont know what to write between {}

Comment: please always give a complete test document (which would say what packages you are using)  `DeclareFloatingEnvironment` for example isn't a standard command,

Comment: it's done !!!!!

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is not a full compilable document.

Comment: Have you tried `\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{plot}}` and `\renewcommand{\theplot}{\arabic{plot}}`?

Comment: I think what David was requesting was a a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that reproduces the problem.

Comment: I made your example into something people could test, please edit it further so it demonstrates the problem. As it is it says FIGURE 1.

Comment: Please tell us which document class you use in your real document. Is it `article`, or maybe something else?

Comment: i'm using Report

Comment: if you are using `report` why did you post an example using `article` (which uses a different numbering scheme)!

Answer (score 4):

Use this code:

```
\documentclass[french]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{newfloat}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[ fileext=lop,
listname={List de figure Partie 2}, name=FIGURE, placement=tp, within=none]{plot}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{plot}{4}
\chapter{ Un Premier Chat Pitre}
\begin{plot}
\centering hhh
\caption{zzz}
\end{plot}

\end{document}
```